# Correct mrtg cfgmaker file

Tags: bash, sed, mrtg

mrtg cfgmaker does read incorrect values over SNMP V1 and V2 and I need to correct the resulting file.

I would like to run a script after creation and use sed if possible.
Lines that needs to be corrected in my case are for LAG's and normal ports:

`MaxBytes[switch01_lag_26]: 125000000` should go to `MaxBytes[switch01_lag_26]: 250000000`

(switch01_lag_26 can be switch01_lag_1 until switch01_lag_26)

`MaxBytes[switch01_g1]: 12500000` should go to `MaxBytes[switch01_g1]: 125000000`

(switch01_g1 can be switch01_g1 until switch01_g16)

What sed patterns I have to use to analyze if its a lag or port in the square brackets and then replace the number after the : ?

The html part should show the correct speed if possible too, this is original for port g1:

```
<h1>Traffic Analysis for g1-- switch01</h1>
             <div id="sysdetails">
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>System:</td>
                                        <td>switch01</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Maintainer:</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Description:</td>
                                        <td>1-Gigabit---Level  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifType:</td>
                                        <td>ethernetCsmacd (6)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifName:</td>
                                        <td>g1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Max Speed:</td>
                                        <td>12.5 MBytes/s</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Ip:</td>
                                        <td>No Ip (No DNS name)</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
```

and should read at the end (Line below "Max Speed" is changed):

```
<h1>Traffic Analysis for g1-- switch01</h1>
             <div id="sysdetails">
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>System:</td>
                                        <td>switch01</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Maintainer:</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Description:</td>
                                        <td>1-Gigabit---Level  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifType:</td>
                                        <td>ethernetCsmacd (6)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifName:</td>
                                        <td>g1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Max Speed:</td>
                                        <td>125.0 MBytes/s</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Ip:</td>
                                        <td>No Ip (No DNS name)</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
```

This is original for LAG 1:

```
<h1>Traffic Analysis for lag 1 -- switch01</h1>
                <div id="sysdetails">
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>System:</td>
                                        <td>switch01</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Maintainer:</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Description:</td>
                                        <td>lag-1  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifType:</td>
                                        <td>IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregate (161)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifName:</td>
                                        <td>lag 1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Max Speed:</td>
                                        <td>125.0 MBytes/s</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Ip:</td>
                                        <td>No Ip (No DNS name)</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
```

which should read at the end (Line below "Max Speed" is changed):

```
<h1>Traffic Analysis for lag 1 -- switch01</h1>
                <div id="sysdetails">
                        <table>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>System:</td>
                                        <td>switch01</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Maintainer:</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Description:</td>
                                        <td>lag-1  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifType:</td>
                                        <td>IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregate (161)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>ifName:</td>
                                        <td>lag 1</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Max Speed:</td>
                                        <td>250.0 MBytes/s</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <td>Ip:</td>
                                        <td>No Ip (No DNS name)</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
```

I can change all speeds in HTML using `sed -i 's/\([0-9.]\+\) MBytes/125.0 MBytes/' /switch01.cfg` but this changes for LAG's too. How to detect if the HTML part belongs to a LAG?

Comment: The only way to make this change (set MaxBytes to be 250M if the interface name starts with 'lag') using cfgmaker itself is to use an Interface Template, which might be the best solution for you as it wouldnt have to be too complex.  If you want to do it post-creation (IE using something like sed) then you could do it with awk.

Comment: Yes that was the solution. I did for each switch a template file. Thanks for the hint